# Installation Error On npm

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, nodejs, npm

when I am installing npm after installing nodejs

```
best@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: nodejs-dev
       Depends: node-request but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
best@ubuntu:~$ npm -v
1.4.28
best@ubuntu:~$ nodejs -v
v0.10.40
best@ubuntu:~$
```

I do not know why the below command not install properly after installing the npm and also its giving me unable to held the broken packages.

```
sudo npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css
sudo npm install -g less
```

and one more things when I will apply below command

```
sudo apt-cache policy nodejs npm
```

Its gives me below output

```
nodejs:
  Installed: 0.10.40-1nodesource1~precise1
  Candidate: 0.10.40-1nodesource1~precise1
  Version table:
 *** 0.10.40-1nodesource1~precise1 0
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_0.10/ precise/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.10.37-1chl1~precise1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
     0.6.12~dfsg1-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
npm:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.1.4~dfsg-1
  Version table:
     1.1.4~dfsg-1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe i386 Packages
```

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy nodejs`

Comment: @A.B. I do not understand why its require packages for my npm installation

Comment: As I said, give me the output of `apt-cache policy nodejs npm`

Comment: @A.B. please try to check my edited Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the installation of the `nodejs` packages from [nodesource](https://nodesource.com/), `npm` is already installed.

In the officially Ubuntu repositories are two separate packages for `npm` and `nodejs` and `npm` depends on `nodejs`, therefore the confusion.

Simply start

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

to fix your system, if there is something to fix, and ignore and don't install the package `npm`.

---

And because I just read that too in your question

> ```
> 0.10.37-1chl1~precise1 0
>    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu/ precise/main i386 Packages
> ```

the same applies if you use the PPA [ppa:chris-lea/node.js](https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/ubuntu/node.js).

Comment: I have already did that one but not yet fixed  from my side

Comment: Usually there is nothing to fix. Ignore and don't install the `npm` package. That's all.